# Minimum count of numbers required from given array to represent S

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an integer S and an array arr[], the task is to find the minimum number of elements whose sum is S, such that an element of the array can be chosen only once to get sum S.

**Example:**

```
Input: arr[] = {25, 10, 5}, S = 30 
Output: 2
```

**Explanation:**

```
Minimum possible solution is 2, (25+5)
```

**Example:**

```
Input: arr[] = {2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6}, Sum= 6 
Output: 1
```

**Explanation:**

```
Minimum possible solution is 1, (6)
```

I have found similar solution [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-count-of-numbers-required-from-given-array-to-represent-s/) but it says element of array can be used multiple times.

I have this code from the link which uses an array element multiple times, but how to restrict this to use only once?

```
static int Count(int S[], int m, int n)
{
    int [][]table = new int[m + 1][n + 1];
 
    // Loop to initialize the array
    // as infinite in the row 0
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    table[0][i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;
    }
 
    // Loop to find the solution
    // by pre-computation for the
    // sequence
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (S[i - 1] > j)
        {
            table[i][j] = table[i - 1][j];
        }
        else
        {
                 
            // Minimum possible for the
            // previous minimum value
            // of the sequence
            table[i][j] = Math.min(table[i - 1][j],
                            table[i][j - S[i - 1]] + 1);
        }
    }
    }
    return table[m][n];
}
 
// Driver Code
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = { 9, 6, 5, 1 };
    int m = arr.length;
     
    System.out.print(Count(arr, m, 11));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic approach for this is to loop backwards when updating the table of previous results.

```
static int minElementsForSum(int[] elems, int sum){
    int[] minElems = new int[sum + 1];
    for(int i = 1; i <= sum; i++) minElems[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int elem: elems) 
        for(int i = sum; i >= elem; i--) 
            if(minElems[i - elem] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) 
              minElems[i] = Math.min(minElems[i], minElems[i - elem] + 1);
    return minElems[sum];
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/s8AG2y)